# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':profile'

Tags: grails, gradle, grails3

I am attempting to upgrade from Grails 3.1.5 to 3.2.2.

When I run `grails --debug --stacktrace run-app` I get the following output:

```
$ grails --debug --stacktrace run-app
|Resolving Dependencies. Please wait...

CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.028 secs
Error |
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':profile'. Type 'gradle dependencies' for more information
```

I tried running `gradle dependencies` but that doesn't seem to tell me anything about what's wrong.

What else can I do to troubleshoot this problem?

**EDIT:** After looking more closely, I noticed this in the `gradle dependencies` output:

```
profile
\--- org.grails.profiles:web: -> 3.2.2 FAILED
```

This seems to be due to the line in my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
```

But when I create a brand new grails 3.2.2 app, that line is also there but things work fine.

What else can I check?

**EDIT:** I compared a new Grails 3.2.2 app with my app, without any version specified for the `profiles` dependency.

For both, in the log of `gradle dependencies --debug` I see:

```
[io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.VersionConfiguringAction]
Using version '3.2.1' for dependency 'org.grails.profiles:web:'
```

The next line with the new app is:

```
[org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder]
Selecting new module version org.grails.profiles:web:3.2.1
```

But with my app:

```
[org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder]
Selecting new module version org.grails.profiles:web:3.2.2
```

So why did it switch to 3.2.2 in the case of my app?

Comment: I just updated my jdk 8 to latest version and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, in my build.gradle file I added an explicit version number of 3.2.1 to the end of the web profile dependency line. This is the version that Grails 3.2.2 is supposed to use by default. I am still not sure why it's pulling in version 3.2.2 when not specified.

```
profile "org.grails.profiles:web:3.2.1"
```

Comment: That is really not a good idea.  You should generate a new project with 3.2.2 and compare its `build.gradle` to the one in your upgraded project.  I expect there is an incompatibility in there.

Comment: See https://github.com/erichelgeson/grails-versions/compare/3.1.5...3.2.2

Comment: Hi Jeff. I tried doing just that - a new 3.2.2 project and comparing the differences. I could not find anything that should have been causing the problem. ... Is there something else I can look at to help troubleshoot this? I'm at a dead-end, other than the "fix" I give here.

Comment: If you can share a link to a project which demonstrates the problem, that would probably be trivial to troubleshoot.

Comment: If I change the version to 3.2.1 it works. When I change it to 3.2.2, it no longer works. ... What is different between these two versions of this dependency? Is there a way I can see more information about *why* the dependency failed? The `gradle dependencies` just says "FAILED" and running with `--debug --stacktrace` doesn't provide any more information.

Comment: Ok here's the error info (looked at grails dependency output with --debug on): `[org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/profiles/web/3.2.2/web-3.2.2.pom]` - try going to that URL - it says "Could not find resource"

Comment: Changing 3.2.1 to 3.2.2 in that URL allows you to successfully download that file. So I wonder if somehow that artifact didn't get deployed correctly to the grails repository?

Comment: For 3.2.2 you should have `profile "org.grails.profiles:web"` without a version number.

Comment: There is no 3.2.2 of the web profile.  The profiles are now versioned independent of Grails releases.

Comment: If you interrogate the box at https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-bom/3.2.2/grails-bom-3.2.2.pom you will see that Grails 3.2.2 by default uses version 3.2.1 of the web profile, but generally you shouldn't express a dependency on that particular version.  You should pull in the one that Grails wants to use by default at this point.

Comment: Just tried with a fresh grails 3.2.2 app and reproduced the error if I explicitly specify the version for the profile dependency, but it works if I omit it. ... It appears that when no version is specified, that 3.2.1 is used.

Comment: "It appears that when no version is specified, that 3.2.1 is used." - That is correct, and is expected.

Comment: See my comment above that links to the 3.2.2 bom.

Comment: "profile "org.grails.profiles:web:3.2.1" - You really probably don't want to do that.  A better idea is to use the version suggested in the bom, which happens to also be 3.2.1 but hardcoding the 3.2.1 in your build file like that is prone to problems in the future.  I would leave the version number off.  It isn't clear what else is wrong in your build that is preventing that from working, but I would chase that down rather than hardcoding 3.2.1. As I said, if you can share a project which demonstrates the problem, it would be trivial to troubleshoot.

Comment: Ok me too. I haven't a clue where else to look. I compared all the dependencies between my app and a new one and can't find anything that is making this happen. I've put in a comment so we can re-address this the next time we upgrade Grails. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Thanks despite the info provided by Jeff I also had to do this workaround in order to get the profile dependency issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been a while since the thread was active, but I thought I could post me solution here to possibly help others with this issue.

I had the same problem with Grails 3.3.3 in IntelliJ Idea.

To resolve the problem I changed the profile to compile in the dependencies list of build.gradle.  This had the effect of causing the file for rest-api to be downloaded. I then changed the compile back to profile as it should be.

running gradle dependencies shows the following for the rest-api profile

```
profile
```

--- org.grails.profiles:rest-api: -> 3.3.2
     --- org.grails.profiles:base:3.3.1

rather than FAILED that I was getting before

Answer (score 0):

If you 're using java 7 for your project, you can do this :
 - compile your prjoect with java 8
 - then run your project with java 7

(this works for me)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced this problem because the CA used by repo.grails.org (Sectigo Limited) was not in Java cacerts. This caused failure to download web profile jar (https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/profiles/web/4.0.0/web-4.0.0.jar).

The solution was to import Sentco root ca cert in cacerts.
I use a separate cacert for my project so I imported into that but for those who want to import at Java level, they need to import into default cacert (${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security/cacerts) using password 'changeit'.